# How do aircraft steer on ground?

Tags: ground-operations

How do modern aircraft steer on the ground? Do they have a steering wheel which moves the front wheel (left/right).

I see that there is a Tug vehicle which pushes the aircraft backwards, so the aircraft does not have a reverse gear for sure.

Does the aircraft use the Engine thrust to move forward on the ground or does it have separate motor which propels the wheels?

Comment: Hi ViSu, welcome to Aviation.SE! Check out this question for details [Taxiing in passenger aircraft](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/are-large-passenger-aircraft-steered-during-taxi-by-changing-the-angle-of-the-fr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these methods are used.

Nosewheel steering is common on most commercial aircraft using a tiller.  Rudder, differential braking, differential thrust and even motors in the wheels (experimental only as far as I know) are also used, [as seen in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xz_eU_l0vMs).

Engine thrust is used to move forward but differential thrust might also be used when negotiating tight turns. *[(Details here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_gear#Steering)*

Comment: You beat me to the answer. Want to expand yours by adding a part about electric taxi motors being tested? I intended to mention that.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the answer and the Wiki link. I think the Wiki page answers lot of my queries.