# How does an aircraft move on the ground?

Tags: ground-operations

Does an aircraft such as Airbus or Boeing have motors similar to cars, so that they turn the wheels?
or do they move on the ground with their engines, the same way they fly?

Comment: [Or this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12328/how-do-aircraft-steer-on-ground) or possibly [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26425/how-do-plane-landing-gear-tyres-roll-before-take-off/26427#26427)

Answer (score 3):

For movement on the ground the aircraft uses it own engines, however since the aircraft cannot move backwards on its own, there are pushback trucks on the airport
[image]

A pushback truck lifts the front weel of the aircraft, their role in most airports is to move the aircraft away from the parking spot on to the taxiways. Here the truck is removed and when all platform staff is out of the way the engines are started one by one. From here on the aircraft moves on its own power to the runway. In the aircraft you will hear the engine spinning up when power is demanded for acceleration.

Comment: Not all push back trucks lift the front wheel off the ground. As a matter of fact, I've never seen one in the US. Usually they use a push bar that attaches to the nose wheel. Same net result, though.

Comment: And the engines are started well before pushback

Comment: @TomMcW  I've only rarely seen engines started before pushback.  On every flight I can recall, the engines are started during pushback.

Comment: A limited number of aircraft can move backwards using their own power.  Some turboprops and most members of the MD-80 family can execute a "powerback".  Ot happened very frequently at DFW.