# How to control yaw in stick aircraft?

Tags: flight-controls, yaw

How do you control yaw in aircraft with a stick control?

It seems like forward and back are used for pitch, and left/right are for roll, so where is the yaw?

Comment: Foot pedals, almost every plane has them. Same way traditional "yoke" controls affect yaw.

Comment: In addition to the selected answer, ground turns are done with the same control on most small aircraft and with a separate [tiller](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1905/3201) on large ones.

Comment: The only plane I can think of that doesn’t use rudder pedals to control yaw is the Ercoupe. It was designed to be non-spinnalbe as a safety measure and the rudder and ailerons were linked to the control wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways that yaw control is achieved.

1. The easiest and the first to be successfully used would be to have cables from rudder pedals on each side of the rudder to deflect the control surface and control yaw.

[image: Rudder Pedals]
<sup>Airplane Flying Handbook pg 2-1</sup>

2. The first application to control yaw unsuccessfully was the development of gears and linkages that will control both roll and yaw with the pilot stick.  It was quickly discovered that there are cases where you may need to use the controls separately.
3. Yaw damper is an electronic device that sense yaw rate and will provide inputs to the rudder to keep the airplane coordinated.

[image: AP YD Picture]

<sup>https://www.gulfcoastavionics.com/images/products/3552/detail/detail.jpg</sup>